# Mac Nginx Passenger configuration for Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, nginx, configuration, passenger

I am using Nginx with Passenger on Mac 10.10.1 below is the Nginx config file

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 5;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    #_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml                 application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript image/png image/gif image/jpeg;

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            #root   html;
            root /Users/harshamv/Sites/nomad/public;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        passenger_enabled on;

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}



    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

    passenger_root /usr/local/opt/passenger/libexec/lib/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
    passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

}
```

Now i am trying to configure my RAils application which is at `/Users/harshamv/Sites/nomad` but i am getting a `403 Forbidden error`

How can i configure the Server to run Passenger as a Application server and Rails Application at the mentioned path?

Is there a way to know if Passenger is configured correctly with Nginx and is running when the server has started?

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-specify `passenger_enabled on` inside any location blocks.

Comment: where should i configure the path to the Rails application? in Passenger or Nginx?

Comment: Since you configure Passenger through the Nginx configuration file, there is no distinction between 'configuring Passenger' and 'configuring Nginx'. But to answer your question: the path to your Rails application is inferred from the 'root' directive. If 'root' is set to your app's 'public' dir, then you're fine. Just don't forget to re-specify `passenger_enabled on` inside any location blocks. `passenger_enabled` is not inherited into sub-contexts.